# Integrating $\int_0^{x'}\sin (f(\xi)\times g(\theta_0))\text d\xi$, where $f(x)=0.777e^{0.1144x}-0.644$

Tags: integration

> How can someone solve an integration like this one?
>
> $$\int_0^{x'}\sin (f(\xi)\times g(\theta_0))\text d\xi = ?$$
>
> where $$f(x)=0.777e^{0.1144x}-0.644$$

Two functions inside a sin function!!

Comment: I have typed out your image, in future, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting pictures as pictures can't be seen by all users and are not searchable

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in terms of elementary functions? Would you consider a numerical approximation? Also is $g(\theta_0)$ constant for varying zeta?

Comment: if possible answers better be in terms of elementary functions.function approximation might be alright (for example sin approximation with polynomials!) but numerical ones will be a lot more difficult for further processing. Also g is independent of zeta and could be considered as a constant.

Comment: lioness99a Thank you for you'r corrections and tip. I'm new here and still need to familiarize myself with this wonderful website! ty